# Jquery draggable - move dragged element instead of duplicating

Tags: jquery, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable

Can someone tell me how best to implement Jquery draggable and droppable so that the dragged element is MOVED to its new position?

Do you need to implement your own helper functions for this, or is it included in the Jquery plugin?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the `helper` option is by default `'original'` which will do exactly what you want, so just leave the option off, or set it to `'original'` and you'll grab the original...as opposed to `'clone'` which makes a copy. It should look like this:

```
$(".element").draggable(function() {
  helper: 'original' //or leave this line off
});
```

[You can test it in the default demo here](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use clone:

```
pnlText.draggable({
    helper: "clone",
    stop: function(event, ui) {
        $(this).css("top",ui.position.top).css("left",ui.position.left);
    }
});
```

This pops the original to the location of the clone when the mouse is let go.